# Spectral radius of a matrix.

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, spectral-radius

Suppose I have a matrix $A$ which has the following property $\rho(A)\leq \rho(A_{\rm sym})$, is it true that $\rho(DAD)\leq \rho(DA_{\rm sym}D)$ for a positive definite diagonal matrix $D$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that $A_{\text{sym}}$ refers to the symmetric part of $A$, i.e., $A_{\text{sym}}=\frac12(A+A^T)$. Then the answer to your question is negative. It should be easy to generate a random counterexample by computer. E.g.
$$
\begin{aligned}
&A=\pmatrix{1&4\\ -2&4},
\quad A_{\text{sym}}=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&4},
\quad D=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&\frac12},\\
&DAD=\pmatrix{1&2\\ -1&1},
\quad DA_{\text{sym}}D=\pmatrix{1&\frac12\\ \frac12&1},\\
&\rho(A)=\sqrt{12}<\frac{\sqrt{12}+\sqrt{13}}{2}<\frac{5+\sqrt{13}}{2}=\rho(A_{\text{sym}}),\\
&\rho(DAD)=\sqrt{3}>\frac32=\rho(DA_{\text{sym}}D).
\end{aligned}
$$